# how use frontmatter-markdown in react js I have a file.md and I want to use Frontend to extract some data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, yaml-front-matter

I have a file.md  and I want to use Frontend to extract some data
This does not work for me
https://hmsk.github.io/frontmatter-markdown-loader/samples-react.html

```
---
    title: "API",
    description: "Restful API",
    category: "API",
    slug: "handle-with-api",
    path: "../articles/api-concept.md"
---
```

---

```
title: "ah",
description: "sdsdds",
category: "API",
slug: "handle-with-sdsdsd",
path: "../articles/dsdsd-concept.md"
```

---

Comment: This does not work for me 
https://hmsk.github.io/frontmatter-markdown-loader/samples-react.html

Comment: Your question could benefit from more detail and specificity both. Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.